# PROC TABULATE with ALL and row percentage

Tags: sas

I am not able to get a row with ALL using row percentages.  I would like the first row to give sum and percentage for column totals. So the percent under borderline for ALL should display 1861 * 100/5049=36.8% and under Desirable to display 1399 * 100/5049=27.7%. Currently it is displaying 100% and I need to change that.

```
proc tabulate data=sashelp.heart;* format=8.2;
 class chol_status smoking_status sex;
 table (all   smoking_status sex), 
    (all chol_status)*(n*f=8. colpctn) ;
run;
```

The output is

```
           All      Cholesterol Status 
                   Borderline Desirable  High  
         N ColPctN N ColPctN N ColPctN N ColPctN 
All     5049 100.00 1861 100.00 1399 100.00 1789 100.00  <- change the cholesterol % to denominator 5049

Smoking Status
Heavy (16-25)   1029 20.38 383 20.58 285 20.37 361 20.18 
Light (1-5)      563 11.15 192 10.32 174 12.44 197 11.01 
Moderate (6-15)  563 11.15 217 11.66 170 12.15 176 9.84 
Non-smoker      2436 48.25 886 47.61 655 46.82 895 50.03 
Very Heavy (> 25) 458 9.07 183 9.83 115 8.22 160 8.94
 
Sex 
Female 2770 54.86 959 51.53 803 57.40 1008 56.34 
Male   2279 45.14 902 48.47 596 42.60 781 43.66
```

Comment: Try moving ALL to after the word?  `table ((smoking_status all) sex)`

Comment: It still gives me 100% for ALL percentages.

Comment: Can you more clearly explain what you're trying to do then? What percentages would you require?

Comment: I would like the first row to give sum and percentage for column totals. So the percent under borderline for ALL should display 1861*100/5049=36.8% and under Desirable to display 1399*100/5049=27.7%.  Currently it is displaying 100% and I need to change that.  Thanks for responding Reeza!

Comment: In other words, for variables I would like COLPCTN and for the universal ALL in the first row I need ROWPCTN.

Comment: Page 5 of this, but in rows, not cols? https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings13/134-2013.pdf

Comment: That doesn't work as it changes the denominator for variables as well, which I do not want.    I have a feeling it is not possible to have ALL as row percentages and variables in column percentages.   Maybe I might need to look into PROC REPORT. Thanks much Reeza!

Comment: I suspect its easier to either fudge the data by including it again as a different variable in your input data set or to pre-summarize and display with PROC REPORT.

Comment: If you post it on communities.sas.com some of the developers can offer advice as well but this is beyond me sadly :(

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest you can get is this:

```
proc tabulate data=sashelp.heart;* format=8.2;
 class chol_status smoking_status sex;
 table all*rowpctn=' '   (smoking_status sex)*(n=' '*f=8. colpctn=' '), 
    (all) (chol_status) ;
run;
```

That's not what you want, though, and doesn't really look very good.  It's the only option that comes out of `proc tabulate`, though, as Tabulate won't let you assign statistics to both the rows and the columns - you have to pick one.

`PROC REPORT` will do what you want, with some effort.  However, you could also run this in a two step process - output the tabulate to a dataset, fix the row percentages, then re-print it, either in Report or Tabulate, not asking it to percentage things that time.

Comment: Thanks Joe!  This is exactly what I want.  Although the results are displayed  in different rows.  Is there a way to get n and percent values to be displayed across columns-in onle line?  I have 50+ covariates so the output is running very long.

Comment: No, that’s what I was saying - you cannot do separate stats that affect both column and row.